# Error on Execution of a SP ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ado.net

```
public DataTable RunProc(String sProcName, SqlParameter[] arrParams) 
{
    string sClassName = "DBAccess.RunProc"; 
    SqlConnection objSqlConnection = null;
    try
    {
        objSqlConnection = (SqlConnection)OpenConnection();
        string sLogMessage="Executing Stored Procedure: ["+ sProcName +"] with Parameters ";
        foreach(SqlParameter objParameter in arrParams)
        {
            sLogMessage+=objParameter.ParameterName+" = ";
            sLogMessage+=objParameter.Value+" ";
        }

        logger.Logns(LogLevel.TraceDetail,sClassName," ",sLogMessage);
        SqlCommand objSqlCommand = CreateCommand(sProcName, arrParams,objSqlConnection,null);
        objSqlCommand.CommandTimeout=300;
        SqlDataAdapter objSQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objSqlCommand);
        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
        objSQLDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);
        this.CloseConnection(objSqlConnection);

        logger.Logns(LogLevel.TraceDetail,sClassName," ","Success Executing Stored Procedure: ["+ sProcName +"]");

        this.CloseConnection(objSqlConnection);
        if( objDataSet.Tables.Count>0)
        {
            return objDataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        //SqlParameter p= new SqlParameter("PACCOUNTNUM", IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Type.VarChar, 17, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, true, ((System.Byte)(0)), ((System.Byte)(0)), "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, null);
    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
        logger.Logns(LogLevel.TraceDetail,sClassName," ","Error Executing Stored Procedure: ["+ Ex.ToString() +"]");
        this.CloseConnection(objSqlConnection);
        throw(new Exception(Ex.ToString()));
    }
}
```

The above mentioned code executes successfully in our production enviroment however all of the sudden we start getting Error in our logs

> 11/04/2011 09:42:46 AM|TraceDetail
>   |DBAccess.RunProc
>   |                              |Error
>   Executing Stored Procedure:
>   [System.Threading.ThreadAbortException:
>   Thread was being aborted.    at
>   SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIPacketGetConnection(IntPtr
>   packet)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ProcessSniPacket(IntPtr
>   packet, UInt32 error)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadPacket(Int32
>   bytesExpected)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String
>   resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method,
>   DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32
>   maxRecords, String srcTable,
>   IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet)    at
>   GDCIEngine.Data.PrismDb.DBAccess.RunProc(String
>   sProcName, SqlParameter[]
>   arrParams)]

The above mentioned code is used in a Web service which is called by presentation layer on the presentation layer i happen to recive HTTP Timedout however on the backend where the service is actually hosted the above mentioned exception is getting printed as soon as i do an iisreset on backend machine every thing start working as expected this error is showing up every now and then and iisreset being the only solution i have come up to cope up with it any help in this regard would be highly appreciated

Thanks
Regards
Azeem

Comment: your code smells, if you use a singleton connection - what if 2 threads open connection? ... who will close it first ...

Comment: Side note: Formatting the code just made me sleepy; use spaces for indentation (or spaces as tabs).

Comment: OpenConnection always returns a new connection and it's not a singleton.

Comment: did you try to increase your sql timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the System.Threading.ThreadAbortException exception.  It's a classic exception [caused by Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/).

Something in your code is code is causing you to attempt to redirect.  Possibly a lost database connection?

Unfortunately, the only way to fix this is to debug it or to try to fix it yourself.

Short of debugging (since it's production), you could try throwing log statements in at specific intervals throughout the function to try to narrow down where the problem is.  e.g.

```
logger.Logns(LogLevel.TraceDetail,sClassName," ","Trace point 1")
... do some stuff ...
logger.Logns(LogLevel.TraceDetail,sClassName," ","Trace point 2")
... do some more stuff ...
logger.Logns(LogLevel.TraceDetail,sClassName," ","Trace point 1")
```

etc.  That might be the only way to track this down.